# julia: Change printed function output

Tags: output, read-eval-print-loop, julia

In julia when a function is called it automatically prints the output to the console i.e.

```
julia> [1:10]+5
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
```

I'm using Gadfly's plotting functions, which creates a plot. The output looks atrocious though. I don't want to completely suppress the output though (I think that can be done using the `;`). I want to retain the `summary` portion (in the above example `10-element Array{Int64,1}`)

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to mess with the REPL?  Something like 'println(summary(ans))' on the next line isn't enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the simple solution is to define a `show` method for Gadfly's plots:

```
Base.show(io::IO,p::Gadfly.Plot) = print(io, summary(p))
```

You can make it more complicated to show more information about `p` if you wish.  In most cases, though, I think Gadfly should actually generate an image of the plot and show it to you (through the richer display mechanism).